# Android objects accessible globally in the class

Tags: android, object, global

how to i make a object of views buttons textviews globally accessible in the activity... i have used the below code but its now working..

```
 private View dummy = (View) View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
 private TextView p1 = (TextView)dummy.findViewById(R.id.player1other);
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(dummy);
 }
 .....
 .....
  public OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.player1:      
        p1.setText(Integer.toString(scores.scores[0])); 

                       break;     }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot give reference of Activity before its initiation. You can do your desired work in this way

```
private View dummy;
 private TextView p1;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(dummy);
        dummy = (View) View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
        p1 = (TextView)dummy.findViewById(R.id.player1other);
 }
 .....
 .....
  public OnClickListener mCorkyListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.player1:      
        p1.setText(Integer.toString(scores.scores[0])); 

                       break;     }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your views as class variable

```
Class A{
EditText edit1;

}
```

edit1 will be accessible anywhere in the class

Answer (score 0):

You need first to call `setContentView()` before using `findViewByID()` in order `findViewByID()` to know where to look for the views. Like this:

```
private TextView p1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    p1 = (TextView)dummy.findViewById(R.id.player1other);
}
```

i.e. first just declare `p1`, then call appropriate `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`,  then initialize `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using this line ....

```
private View dummy = (View) View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
```

Use this

```
LayoutInflater l1 = this.getLayoutInflater();
private View dummy = l1.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private TextView p1;

@Override
public void onCreate(savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    p1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1other);
}
```

and the rest is just the same.